# I have an iphone application which uses dragging of annotations on a MapView, is this possible is the iPad?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, annotations, mapkit

I am trying to use:

```
(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView
             :(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView didChangeDragState
             :(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState fromOldState
             :(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState
```

And was getting errors when building this for the iPad, but I have since realised that it is iOS 4 specific, so it won't work on the iPad.  Is there anything similar that I can use for the iPad?

Answer (score 0):

1°) You should wrap your code with < pre >< /pre > or do a crt+k

2°) You can wait the iOS 4.2 for iPad that is currently under beta2. I will be released in 1 month. Or you can buy a apple developer account (100$ / year) and then download the Beta SDK :-)

I don't know what else you could else, but good Luck !